# What Type Of Camshaft Location is most common?

Tags: engine-theory, camshaft

I want to know what type of camshaft location is most common in most vehicles? Is it an OHV/DOHV or OHC/DOHC/SOHC

Comment: I'm enjoying the questions you're asking. As as suggestion you might consider thinking of your questions in terms of, for example, the benefits and costs of different camshaft locations vs. which is most common. I think that could lead us to better answers and will probably get you closer to the information your really want.

Answer (score 2):

They are all common in different configurations.

OHV is most common in V style engines, since you can have a single cam in the middle of the block.  This weighs less than having a cam over each head, plus the belt/chain to drive it.  This is most common in large 'truck' engines that need power at low RPM.

SOHC is common on all engines.  SOHC is used typically on "low end" economy engines, or engines that need to make max power at lower RPM.

DOHC is also common on all engines.  These engines tend to produce power at higher RPM as most DOHC engines have 4 valves per cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all DOHV is not in production period.

Most cheap engines especially ones with lower capacity and power outputs use SOHC configuration like the suzuki 1.2L engine or G13B which are all sub 1.8L engines.

Also, if you take the raw count, then I would say, yes the SOHC is the most produced configuration since 90% of motorcycles in developing countries like India and Vietnam have a huge number of single cylinder SOHC configured bikes and mopeds.

The Second most Common configuration is the DOHC setup which almost all of the modern cars use and is pretty much the standard for automotive engines apart from some chevy engines.

The third popular alternative , which is dying and is in its final stages is the OHV configuration which only a few Chevy and GM engines use now a days.Needless to say that some shipping engines and electricity generators use OHV today due to its advantages and since the generators run at a constant speed OHVs do the job best.

Comment: I agree with you for the most part, but realize GM will not be going away from the OHV configuration. Yes, this configuration has slipped away from a production standpoint, GM is sticking by this configuration for one simple reason: people like to drive it better than an OHC configuration. In a blind study of both configurations, the OHV config was preferred by those who tested.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  How can they tell??  I'd love to see that A/B/X double blind.  Got a reference please?

Comment: @SteveRacer - I read an article about what GM did (it was written by R&T or the like). I didn't say it was a double blind, but just a blind study. They had two Corvettes which they put a DOHC engine into one and a OHV engine in the other (same basic power levels). Everyone who drove both preferred the OHV configuration. This and the OHV having the lower center of gravity lends to it in their performance cars. The fact the OHV has better low end torque shows why it's in the trucks. This decision was made around the time for the LS1 design considerations. (I haven't found the article again.)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 If the torque curve was different it wasn't apples-apples, so I can imagine a perceptible difference.  But camshaft location doesn't change torque.  Lift, duration, number of valves, intake runner length... sure.  But I get it now-- thanks

Comment: @SteveRacer - Camshaft location doesn't change torque, but a DOHC with 4 valves per, does. DOHC may help with top end HP, but it hurts low end torque in the process (cam phasers or VVT can help with this, though). Yah, I stumbled onto the article and haven't been able to find it again ... *and I've looked*, lol.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 You are right in terms of OHV providing slightly better torque figures than DOHC but it robs you a LOT MORE than its giving you , Also aiming for centre of gravity in a Muscle car plainly does not make sense to me at all. Its not like the camaros and Mustangs are as good as a GTR or an EVO at taking corners or subaru(Boxer makes sense here) but on a muscle car having to switch to OHV just for low COG does not make sense.

Comment: @SteveRacer You can actually tell the difference between a OHV and an SOHC and a DOHC motor , OHV and SOHC will behave similarly where you will have tons of torque in the low to mid range but DOHC on the other hand will usually Generate peak HP and Torque and much higher RPMs and are generally not practically useful on city roads.

Comment: @Anarach - You really aren't thinking much of the newer generations of sports cars, including Mustangs, Camaros, and Corvettes. The Corvette with the Z06/Z07 packages out corners any of those you are talking about ([1.20G on the skid pad](http://www.corvetteonline.com/features/editorials-opinions/editors-choice-the-c7-stingray-versus-the-z06/)) right off the showroom floor.

Comment: @Anarach. no, sorry, I don't share your religion. There's absolutely no doubt that the number of valves, their size, their duration, and their lift would change the torque and power curves.  But my assertion was camshaft *location*, and I hope you're not going to tell me one can distinguish between a cam in the valley vs. one in each head, ALL other parameters that effect volumetric efficiency being equal. That was my confusion from the start; I never doubted a driver could distinguish very different torque curves.  Other than lower rev limits, you can't *smell* pushrods...

Comment: @SteveRacer I have driven a 200cc motorbike with SOHC config outputting 17bhp and 15 NM of Torque which feels much better in the city and under 60 mph than a 250 CC DOHC 25hp motorcycle with 20NM of torque, I am not saying you jump into a vehicle and you can say that which cam profile the vehicle has but generally SOHC and OHVs have much better low end torque than DOHC. That is why trucks which need a lot of low end torque use OHV config.

Comment: @SteveRacer Ok i understood your point, Yes you cannot smell PUSHRODS but if a vehicle has torque and power at high RPM then its most definately DOHC so if the vehicle has low end torque then MAY be SOHC or OHV not definitely but MAYBE but not usually , that is my point.

Comment: @Anrach yep,you are absolutely correct but we are so far from the OP original question....  I only meant that camshaft *location* has no special characteristics.  Mercedes pulled a nice *fast one rules are rules* on formula cars a few years ago gaining *rules* displacement with  their  [2 inch] pushrod motor.  My ultimate point is that VE is king; where you locate your camshaft(s) is a matter of crafty engineering.  I'm still not ready to say quad cam, or just DOHC, is any different unless the total valve area is different, or you can now vary intake/exhaust timing with RPM.  It's all good!